# How to Capture image without preview

Tags: android, android-camera

My requirement is that i want to capture images when my application is running and then at the end show the images to the user. So how can i capture the image without showing the preview and my application will also be focused during capturing.

Thanks in advance please quickly......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wait..... man what about using FrameLayout and placing my layout over the surface view

Answer (score 0):

If by "capture images" you mean "take pictures with the camera", you have to show preview mode.

Comment: but i want to take pictures during the execution of my app. User will interact with my app and will not know about the camera. that's the requirement. i don't want to show preview.

Comment: @Hamdullah shah: You have no choice but to show the preview. Among other things, it allows the user to know that the camera is in operation. Tell whoever gave you the requirement that it is impossible on Android.

Comment: wait..... man what about using FrameLayout and placing my layout over the surface view.